# `scrapy crawl` not working on MacOS 10.15.6

Tags: python, scrapy

I am writing a scraper for a website using `scrapy` but I am getting a few errors.

Here’s what I am doing -

- Created a virtual environment
- Tried installing `scrapy`
- Got the following error while installing scraps -

```
    **ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:**
     command: /Users/arif/newcoderProjects/scrape/ScrapProj/bin/python3 -u -c ‘import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = ‘”’”’/private/var/folders/p0/42wg04b16q794pj9b67zxx340000gn/T/pip-install-qavbn6kl/Twisted/setup.py’”’”’; __file__=‘”’”’/private/var/folders/p0/42wg04b16q794pj9b67zxx340000gn/T/pip-install-qavbn6kl/Twisted/setup.py’”’”’;f=getattr(tokenize, ‘”’”’open’”’”’, open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace(‘”’”’\r\n’”’”’, ‘”’”’\n’”’”’);f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, ‘”’”’exec’”’”’))’ install —record /private/var/folders/p0/42wg04b16q794pj9b67zxx340000gn/T/pip-record-n45b36ca/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/arif/newcoderProjects/scrape/ScrapProj/include/site/python3.8/Twisted
         cwd: /private/var/folders/p0/42wg04b16q794pj9b67zxx340000gn/T/pip-install-qavbn6kl/Twisted/
```

- I believed that it got installed and tried running `scrapy crawl xyz` and got the error: `bash: scrapy: command not found`

How can I fix this error? I also have a problem in PATH, could that be the issue, it is described here -

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the problem was in my PATH and because of that while installing `scrapy`, something called Twisted wasn't being set up. Upon fixing PATH, `pip install scrapy` works.